# Ruby Each Do Variable Substitution

Tags: ruby, each

This is the contents of a each loop, names.each do|x| . I need to substitute v02 with #{x} but am having trouble with the syntax. Please show me how to replace v02 with x.

```
<% @a = Count.find_by_user_id(@user) %>
<% @b = @a.v02 %>
<% @c = @b * 1.0 %>
<% @d = Carpart.find_by_part("v02") %>
<% @e = @d.requirement %>
<% @f = @c / @e %>
<% @g = @f * 100 %>
<% @h = [@g, 100].min %>
<% @i = Percentage.find_by_user_id(@user) %>
<% @i.update_attribute(:v02, @h) %>
V02 <%= @i.v02 %>%
<% @v02 = @i.v02 %>
```

Comment: You're doing this all in a view? All that logic would much more happily live in the model (Name?) that's you're iterating a collection of. Also, how's @user getting populated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not completely sure if that's what you meant, but... Did you mean like this?

```
<% @a = Count.find_by_user_id(@user) %>
<% @b = @a.send(x) %>
<% @c = @b * 1.0 %>
<% @d = Carpart.find_by_part("#{x}") %>
<% @e = @d.requirement %>
<% @f = @c / @e %>
<% @g = @f * 100 %>
<% @h = [@g, 100].min %>
<% @i = Percentage.find_by_user_id(@user) %>
<% @i.update_attribute(x.to_sym, @h) %>
x <%= @i.send(x) %>%
<% @x = @i.send(x) %>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Ruby's `send`

```
<% @b = @a.send(x) %>
```

Or

```
<% @b = @a.__send__(x) %>
```

I prefer the latter only because, you usually don't have to worry about anyone overriding that one.

Comment: ty! i was missing the send(x)